# Version maintenance of artifacts in artifactory, when we do bug fixing in various environments

Tags: artifactory, artifacts

We use `artifactory` as a repo manager. We store packages for releases in repo `libs-release-local` and snapshot packages in `libs-snapshot-local`.

For example: If we send the `war` (web app) into test, it should be from `libs-snapshot-local` and if it is into stage & prod it will be from `libs-release-local`.

I will say a scenario, where I needed help below:

Once the `war` is certified good on test server we would send the same code to stage.

We saw a bug after deployed into stage, so we changed the code and again build it, it obviously cannot go to same versioned release(as in artifactory, we cannot override releases).

So,

1. What will happen if we recognized 10 bug fixes one at a time, after each deployment in stage ?
2. What if we have realized there are bug fixes after going to prod.

Artifactory will have bulk of folders with so many version names & folders. Is that good practice? Or else anything senses wrong in our procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I know the reason for down vote? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to read [Binary repository management Refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/binary-repository-management) first.

You need define your strategy for your folders and wars (web application), it is already good to use different repo for different purpose (snapshot/release)

The process for maintenance is simple

1. fix the bug and increase the version, send to the `libs-snapshot-local` for testing
2. after testing, a.k.a QA passed, the packages are **promoted** to release/stage repo `libs-release-local` again for public use again.

In this case, bug fix is the same as normal development procedure.

or you can refine the questions to make your questions more clear.

Comment: Thanks for that link Larry. It was helpful. But regarding increasing version, lets assume I have deployed a war from 1.0 version in libs-releases initially and identified a bug after deployment. So we made a code change & it goes through snapshots and then promoted to releases next version(say 1.1). Let us assume that I found 8 other bugs each at a time after deployment. So the version will be going on like until 1.9. Is that a good process having 10 folders (1.0 - 1.9) or do we have any workaround for this?

Comment: depends on whether the war files with different bug fix need to be released or not. Mostly they can be patched together in next release 1.1. Version here is related with release instead of code changes. It is related your release version strategy, not artifactory tool.